# Azure Easy API on Node.js 'No route registered for '/api/xxx'?

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm having problems even running a simple Easy API method.  I keep getting the response that says "No route registered for '/api/userInfo'".

I know that this location is correct because the I'm opening the App Service editor at https://XXXX/dev/wwwroot/api/userInfo.js

The file also has anonymous access, so there shouldn't be an authorization issue.  I'm simply trying to hit the api method from a browser.

The code of this very simple method has been reduced to the following for debugging purposes

```
module.exports = {
    "get":function(){
        console.log('whooohooo');
    }
};
```

Is there a setting I'm missing to enable the ability to call Easy API's?  I've not been able to find any documentation that states that Easy APIs method must be explicitly enabled, nor can I find any settings related to enabling them.

Please note that I did not set up a Node.js project and deploy it to Azure.  I am using an "out of the box" app service.

My end goal is to use an Easy API method go get an authenticated user's email and name, but my efforts have been reduced to confirming that I can call a method.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I've created 3 different mobile App services with no luck and varying advantages.

**App Service 1:**
This Mobile Apps project is 10 months old and was created in the Azure portal.  It has a routing line in the app.js file that suggest that the api route should be present, but doesn't work.  I don't remember if i authorized the easy apis when i created it, but the fact that it has the following line suggests that I did

```
mobile.api.import('./api');
```

**AppService 2:**
This project was created in the MobileCenter using the Tables menu option for a Xamarin project.  I then navigated to the Azure Portal and hooked up a SQL db to the table.  I don't think I had the opt in to use Easy APIs, but the I was allowed to create an Easy API script, then edit it.  **Upon editing it, I realized that the project had no app.js fil**e.  Apparently web apps created via MobileCenter are created differently.

I picked this option because it allows you to use the "per-user" flag when setting up tables and doesn't require you to manually filter out data with a modification to the table's script. Apparently this is not an option if you don't set up an App Service via the MobileCenter??

**App Service 3:**
I created a brand new project within the portal and followed the the steps Aaron Chen laid out.  I opted in, hooked up the table and modified the js file (I created a new one called 'testing').  I browsed to https://zzzzapitestzzzz1.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/testing

and got the dreaded no routes found error. Of course, the API method was created with anon access rights.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we can easily create an Easy API in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

1. Select your app service and click on **Easy APIs** in the **MOBILE** menu.
2. Enable Mobile extension for your app by clicking `Need to configure Easy Tables/Easy APIs ...`

[image]

3. Connect a database and then click **Initialize App** button.

[image]

4. After app initialized, you can add an API from **Easy APIs** blade.

[image]

5. Change the `userInfo.js` file to something like this:

[image]

6. Now, we can access the API with the endpoint `http://<yourappname>.azurewebsites.net/api/userInfo`.

[image]

For more info, please refer to [this blog post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-20-custom-api/).

Comment: Thanks for the response Aaron.  I'm still having the problem but i noticed that projects created via the MobileCenter do not have an app.js file so I started testing with a new project.  I've updated my finding in the original post.

Comment: Please don't include `.scm` in your URL. Browse to this: https://zzzzapitestzzzz1.azurewebsites.net/api/testing

Comment: THANK YOU!  I can't believe I missed that.  Its funny how one small oversight will send you down the rabbit hole. Thanks again!